# JNI local reference table summary (512 entries)

Tags: java, android, resources, android-resources

I have more than 10000 city names and i want to show in ListView. I stored those names as city.xml file in `res/values folder`

like below

```
<resources>
<string-array name="city"> 
<item>  chennai, India </item>
<item>  Spring Creek , Australia </item>
.
.
```

Then I create a ArrayAdapter and populate to listView like this.

```
String[] cityDetails = res.getStringArray(R.array.city); // <-- getting Error in this line
myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.ap_details_row, R.id.aNameTV, cityDetails );
myLV.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

It works fine in API level 13 and above devices. But below API level 13 devices, I get the following error.

```
 W/dalvikvm(306): ReferenceTable overflow (max=512)
 W/dalvikvm(306): Last 10 entries in JNI local reference table:
  W/dalvikvm(306):   502: 0x45fbb330 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
  W/dalvikvm(306):   503: 0x45fbb388 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
  W/dalvikvm(306):   504: 0x45fbb3e0 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
  W/dalvikvm(306):   505: 0x45fbb438 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
  W/dalvikvm(306):   506: 0x45fbb498 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
  W/dalvikvm(306):   507: 0x45fbb4f8 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
  W/dalvikvm(306):   508: 0x45fbb558 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
  W/dalvikvm(306):   509: 0x45fbb5d0 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
  W/dalvikvm(306):   510: 0x45fbb638 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
  W/dalvikvm(306):   511: 0x45fbb698 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
  W/dalvikvm(306): JNI local reference table summary (512 entries):
  W/dalvikvm(306):     3 of Ljava/lang/Class; 164B (2 unique)
  W/dalvikvm(306):   507 of Ljava/lang/String; 28B (507 unique)
  W/dalvikvm(306):     1 of [Ljava/lang/String; 28B
  W/dalvikvm(306):     1 of [Ljava/lang/String; 37436B
  W/dalvikvm(306): Memory held directly by tracked refs is 51988 bytes
  E/dalvikvm(306): Failed adding to JNI local ref table (has 512 entries)
  I/dalvikvm(306): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
  I/dalvikvm(306):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4001d8e0 self=0xccb0
  I/dalvikvm(306):   | sysTid=306 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345026008
  I/dalvikvm(306):   | schedstat=( 1050455605 562911400 652 )
  I/dalvikvm(306):   at android.content.res.AssetManager.getArrayStringResource(Native Method)
  I/dalvikvm(306):   at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceStringArray(AssetManager.java:186)
  I/dalvikvm(306):   at android.content.res.Resources.getStringArray(Resources.java:381)
  I/dalvikvm(306):   at com.mypro.main.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:184)
 I/dalvikvm(306):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 E/dalvikvm(306): VM aborting
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following method worked  fine in all API levels.

```
     ArrayList<String> namelist = null;
        try {

             AssetManager am = activity.getAssets();
             InputStream is = am.open("city_name_list.txt");
             Scanner inStream = new Scanner(is);
             namelist = new ArrayList<String>();

            while(inStream.hasNextLine()){
                    namelist.add(inStream.nextLine());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

A few ideas:

1- Display data one page at a time. When you scroll down, load more data.

2- Scrolling through 10000 records to go to the end will take forever. Access your data via a search form. Limit results to 100 records.

3- If the data is sorted, group items together and provide an index. For example, alphabetical lists can be split into 26 subsets. The first page shows the alphabet, and you have to click on a letter to go to a subset.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use Base Adapter... It loads lazily~~~

Answer (score 2):

I Think You have To Use "`AutoCompleteText`" rather then "`ListView`" because end user it easy to find city from more data.

Answer (score 2):

It is **not good practice** to show listview with 10 000 city names. You should consider using another approach.

For example, take look at [**AutoCompleteTextView**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html).

Comment: Then i dont understand why would your user want to see 10000 city names. What is your use-case or motivation for this?

Answer (score 1):

Another thought would be to insert these values into a sqlite database and access them using a CursorLoader. The cursor will handle the memory management of all the data.

Here's a great tutorial on SQLite on Android: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html